# How to check table exist and then rename it

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

This question is similar to many other question but it have many other things to.

I Have to create a query in which I have many thing:

> First check if table is already exist in the database or not which I know we can get from this

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'x'))
```

> Second I need to update the table name if it is already an existing table

```
EXEC sp_rename 'x','y'
```

> Third I have to check if it is not exist create it and then load the data from text file into database using bcp for that I know code is like this.

```
Create table x(id int, number varchar(20))

Declare @cmd varchar(200)
Set @cmd='BCP master.dbo.x IN 'filePath' -S -T f -t, -C -E'
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd
```

I know each and every thing separately I just need your guidance how can I achieve all this in one single Sql query.

For example:

> I don't have any table with name 'x' in database, so my query first check if their is any table with the name x or not if no then it will create one and load data from bcp, if table is already existing then it will update the name of the table and then load the data using bcp.
>
> Once the file loaded and we have updated name of the table query will run again and it check the table name and same process so I guess I cant take any hard coded value in my query.

Updated Code:

```
Declare @z varchar(100)
Set @z='x' 

IF Object_ID(@z) is null
Print 'Table not EXISTS' 
Else Print 'EXISTS'

 Declare @cmd varchar(200)
Set @cmd='BCP @z IN 'filePath' -S -T f -t, -C -E'
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd

DECALRE @name varchar(200)
set @name= @z+'_'+(convert(varchar(16),GETDATE(),112))
EXEC sp_Rename @z,@name
```

First 2 time it work fine although I m working only on the existing table.
In 3rd time it will check for x table but in 2nd attempt it is already update to x_systemdate now I just need to know how can I change it every time query run.

Any help appreciated !!

Comment: ...just put all the scripts together as is and run it as one?

Comment: I just edit my ques and put one example what I require can u pls look at it and suggest :)

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you run it a third time and you have `x` and `y` already?

Comment: let me show you my updated code which I created

Comment: @Pred check my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options, one is to do the whole thing using dynamic queries. You can also take a look at SQLCMD. I will show you a quick mock up of the dynamic SQL solution.

```
DECLARE @TableSchema sys.sysname = N'dbo';
DECLARE @TableName sys.sysname = N'x';
DECLARE @BackupTable sys.sysname = @TableName + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), GETDATE(), 112);


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'

DECLARE @TableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
             AND  TABLE_NAME = @TableName))
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_rename @TableWithSchema, @BackupTable, ''OBJECT''
END

CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '(
/* Column definitions here*/
);
';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @stmt = @SQL
  , @params = N'@TableSchema sys.sysname, @TableName sys.sysname, @BackupTable sys.sysname'
  , @TableSchema = @TableSchema
  , @TableName = @TableName
  , @BackupTable = @BackupTable
;

/* Do BCP here */
```

Please note, that 112 date format (see convert) does not contain time value, therefore you want to change it in order to allow the script to run multiple times a day. You can go for example with `select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), GETDATE(), 120), ' ', ''), ':', ''), '-', '')` (yyyyMMddHHmmss) instead

As always, be careful and double check your code when you are working with dynamic queries!

Comment: I guess sp_executesql is used in t-sql I m using sql server 2008

Comment: then you don't have CONCAT, you can use + instead. sp_executesql is available in 2008. Edited the answer to be compatible with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Yes I did, however you should be able to do so too.

Comment: in this code suppose I have no table with name x so I m doing it for the first time, when I run it for the first time it will create a table with x when I run it second time it should update the existing one name with x_getdate() but it is creating new file and when I run it 3rd time it is throwing error after I m doing bcp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147470/discussion-between-pred-and-amitesh).

Comment: Hi Pred I am still stuck at that position