# how to keep updating the name a table in query

Tags: sql, bcp

PFB link in which I reach to a point where I m stuck

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718300/how-to-check-table-exist-and-then-rename-it/44721382#44721382)

In my previous code I get all the details expect one point

> in that code suppose I have no table with name x so I m doing it for the first time, when I run it for the first time it will create a table with x when I run it second time it should update the existing table name with x_getdate() but it is creating new table.

So I was thinking what is the approach I follow should I change that code and try to create new one or should I stick to that code and start modifying details in that only and also I am thing if I need to update the existing code what is the best thing I can do. I am paste my current code here also :

```
DECLARE @TableSchema sys.sysname = N'dbo';
DECLARE @TableName sys.sysname = N'x';
DECLARE @BackupTable sys.sysname = @TableName + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR  (32),    GETDATE(), 120);


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'

DECLARE @TableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + ''.'' +    QUOTENAME(@TableName);

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
         AND  TABLE_NAME = @TableName))
 BEGIN
 EXEC sp_rename @TableWithSchema, @BackupTable, ''OBJECT''
 END

 CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '(
 /* Column definitions here*/
 );
 ';

  EXEC sp_executesql
  @stmt = @SQL
 , @params = N'@TableSchema sys.sysname, @TableName sys.sysname, @BackupTable sys.sysname'
 , @TableSchema = @TableSchema
 , @TableName = @TableName
, @BackupTable = @BackupTable
 ;

 DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(8000)
 SET @CMD='BCP db..'+@TableName+' IN file path -T -f -t,-c -E'
 EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @CMD
```

Comment: You never accepted an answer in your previous question.  Maybe you should do that if you expect others to help here.

Comment: ok sure @TimBiegeleisen I did that

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen any thing you want to suggest on iit